# Jhipster gulp build throwing error File not found with singular glob

Tags: gulp, jhipster

I am using angularJs version of webapp generated via jHipster.
Here is my gulp file:

```
    // Generated on 2018-05-21 using generator-jhipster 4.14.3
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    rev = require('gulp-rev'),
    templateCache = require('gulp-angular-templatecache'),
    htmlmin = require('gulp-htmlmin'),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    ngConstant = require('gulp-ng-constant'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    eslint = require('gulp-eslint'),
    del = require('del'),
    runSequence = require('run-sequence'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync'),
    KarmaServer = require('karma').Server,
    plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
    changed = require('gulp-changed'),
    gulpIf = require('gulp-if'),
    wbBuild = require('workbox-build');

var handleErrors = require('./gulp/handle-errors'),
    serve = require('./gulp/serve'),
    util = require('./gulp/utils'),
    copy = require('./gulp/copy'),
    inject = require('./gulp/inject'),
    build = require('./gulp/build');

var config = require('./gulp/config');

...

gulp.task('inject', function() {
    runSequence('inject:dep', 'inject:app');
});

gulp.task('inject:dep', ['inject:test', 'inject:vendor']);

gulp.task('inject:app', inject.app);

gulp.task('inject:vendor', inject.vendor);

gulp.task('assets:prod', ['images', 'styles', 'html', 'copy:swagger', 'copy:images'], build);

gulp.task('html', function () {
    return gulp.src(config.app + 'app/**/*.html')
        .pipe(htmlmin({collapseWhitespace: true}))
        .pipe(templateCache({
            module: 'getWellnessHomeApp',
            root: 'app/',
            moduleSystem: 'IIFE'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.tmp));
});

gulp.task('ngconstant:prod', function () {
    return ngConstant({
        name: 'getWellnessHomeApp',
        constants: {
            VERSION: util.parseVersion(),
            DEBUG_INFO_ENABLED: false,
            BUILD_TIMESTAMP: new Date().getTime()
        },
        template: config.constantTemplate,
        stream: true
    })
    .pipe(rename('app.constants.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.app + 'app/'));
});

// check app for eslint errors
gulp.task('eslint', function () {
    return gulp.src(['gulpfile.js', config.app + 'app/**/*.js'])
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        .pipe(eslint())
        .pipe(eslint.format())
        .pipe(eslint.failOnError());
});

// check app for eslint errors anf fix some of them
gulp.task('eslint:fix', function () {
    return gulp.src(config.app + 'app/**/*.js')
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        .pipe(eslint({
            fix: true
        }))
        .pipe(eslint.format())
        .pipe(gulpIf(util.isLintFixed, gulp.dest(config.app + 'app')));
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('bower.json', ['install']);
    gulp.watch(['gulpfile.js', 'build.gradle'], ['ngconstant:dev']);
    gulp.watch(config.app + 'content/css/**/*.css', ['styles']);
    gulp.watch(config.app + 'content/images/**', ['images']);
    gulp.watch(config.app + 'app/**/*.js', ['inject:app']);
    gulp.watch([config.app + '*.html', config.app + 'app/**', config.app + 'i18n/**']).on('change', browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('install', function () {
    runSequence(['inject:dep', 'ngconstant:dev'], 'copy:languages', 'inject:app', 'inject:troubleshoot');
});

gulp.task('serve', ['install'], serve);

gulp.task('build', ['clean'], function (cb) {
    runSequence(['copy', 'inject:vendor', 'ngconstant:prod', 'copy:languages'], 'inject:app', 'inject:troubleshoot', 'assets:prod', 'bundle-sw');
});

gulp.task('default', ['serve']);
```

When I am doing gulp build, it's throwing following error and not creating build properly.
[image: Gulp build error messages]

I checked [Gulp throwing error: File not found with singular glob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36839828/gulp-throwing-error-file-not-found-with-singular-glob)
But this doesn't work with me whatsoever.

Gulp serve is working fine.

I installed similar web app via jHipster and compared all the gulp files.
I am not able to locate the actual cause at all.

Please advise.

Cheers.

Comment: Which node version? Which version of Windows ? Have you tried a prod build using maven? It could help because it uses an isolated environment for node. also the path of the file is strange because it refers to generator-jhipster templates which should not be used, like if your project was configured wrongly to look for static assets anywhere even in node_modules folder rather than only in your project sources.

Comment: It is having backend and web app separate, so war is building correctly. As you mentioned I think the file path could be the issue. Still trying.